# How to set TooltipService.Tooltip on a PivotItem?

Tags: c#, uwp

I need to set the TooltipService.Tooltip to a PivotItem, how can I do this?

This model isn't working

```
<PivotItem Header="Link 1" ToolTipService.ToolTip="test 1">

</PivotItem>
```

Comment: Can't you do `ToolTip = "FooBar"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <Pivot >
        <PivotItem x:Name="L" Header="Link 1"  ToolTipService.ToolTip="test 1" ToolTipService.PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=L}" > </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
```

You must give the PlacementTarget that can use x:Name and you can set the ToolTipService.Placement